# Validate Web Address Input - jQuery Form Validation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my form field to validate that a valid web URL has been entered. But it's not working...no matter how long I search around...what am I doing wrong?

Note, default value on form `<input>` is "http://".

```
        if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(web_url)){
            alert('Please enter valid URL');
            // Do nothing
            return false;
        };
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `x` regex modifier. What does console say?

Comment: Removed the `x`. Still doesn't work...

Comment: Not overly familiar with console. But not errors are showing...

Comment: What's happening and what isn't?

Comment: Oh, and that if statement shouldn't end with a semicolon.

Comment: Move your regex outside the if statement so it's more easily readable. Having it inside the if statement is messy

Comment: @Walkerneo, The field doesn't get validated. I can enter anything in it and it will submit...

Comment: @Bankzilla...I'll add it to a variable after. I agree.

Comment: So I added an `!` to the beginning... `if(!/^(http|https|ftp)...etc`. Is this right?